# why hypersurface is called hypersurface and not Hyposurface

Tags: manifolds

from wikipedia:
"Suppose an enveloping manifold M has n dimensions; then any submanifold of M of n − 1 dimensions is a hypersurface"

Now, hyper- is the prefix of "over"
hypo- is the prefix of "under"

If we move form n to n-1 soundn't it be called Hyposurface?

Comment: I believe the "hyper" prefix is used since hypersurfaces are the higher-dimensional analogs of regular two-dimensional surfaces?

Comment: @Vhailor- Publish your comment as a question and I will select it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hyper" prefix is used since hypersurfaces are the higher-dimensional analogs of regular two-dimensional surfaces.

It is used in the same way in expressions such as "hyperplane" and "hypercube".